# Javascript - Problem comparing dates

Tags: javascript

The code below is giving me trouble.  When I select July 1st 11:00pm for fromDate, result 3 is being set to Thu Jun 02 2011 11:52:26.  I check the values of fromDate and toDate in chrome and they seem fine but result 3 is getting set to a wacky date.  Any solutions?

```
function(value, element, params) {
            fromDate = new Date(startDate.val());
            toDate = new Date(endDate.val());
            result1 = this.optional(element);
            result2 = fromDate <= toDate;
            result3 = new Date();
            result3.setDate(fromDate.getDate()+1);
            result5 = (toDate.getDate()+0);
            result4 = (fromDate.getDate()+1)>(toDate.getDate()+0);
            return result1 || (result2 && result4);
        }
```

Comment: Can you include more information?  It's not not totally clear what is the problem and what is being asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result3.setDate(fromDate.getDate()+1)` only sets the day of the month of your Date object. Since `result3` creates a new Date object, this means that `result3` is not having its time set correctly.

If you want to set `result3` to `fromDate` plus one day, you'll have to do something like this:

```
var DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
result3 = new Date(fromDate + DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

However, since I'm not sure what your variables represent, it's hard to diagnose.